# What does NSString's isLike: actually do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to figure out what `isLike:` actually does to `NSString`s and having trouble. Apple's [own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/index.html) is very vague:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is "like"
>   another given object.
>
> ...
>
> The default implementation for this method provided by `NSObject` method
>   returns `NO`. `NSString` also provides an implementation of this method,
>   which returns `YES` if the receiver matches a pattern described by
>   object.

It mentions a "pattern", but with some rudimentary testing, it does not appear to be using regular expressions. What exactly is the pattern format in this case?

Comment: Does it match up with the behavior of [the `LIKE` operator from `NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell `*` works as described there, but it also does substring comparison to some extent... so "FooBar" isLike "Foo"

Comment: @Earlz, I tried `[@"FooBar" isLike:@"Foo"]` but got a false result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have posted, Apple's documentation does not describe the behavior of `[NSString isLike:]` in detail as seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/isLike:):

> The default implementation for this method provided by NSObject method returns NO. NSString also provides an implementation of this method, which returns YES if the receiver matches a pattern described by object.

As others suggested it may be based on `NSPredicate`.  If so it is likely using `NSComparisonPredicate` with operator type `NSLikePredicateOperatorType` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPredicateOperatorType):

> NSMatchesPredicateOperatorType
>
> A full regular expression matching predicate.
>
> Available in OS X v10.4 and later.
>
> NSLikePredicateOperatorType
>
> A simple subset of the MATCHES predicate, similar in behavior to SQL LIKE.
>
> Available in OS X v10.4 and later.

Although the functionality may be a simple subset of regular expressions, the syntax is definitely different.  I tested the following locally on OS X 10.10.5 Today:

```
- (NSString *)escapeString:(NSString *)value {
    return [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
}

- (void)is:(NSString *)value like:(NSString *)pattern note:(NSString *)note {
    NSLog(@"[@\"%@\" isLike:@\"%@\"] == %@ // %@",
            [self escapeString:value],
            [self escapeString:pattern],
            ([value isLike:pattern] ? @"true" : @"false"),
            note);
}

- (void)testAll {
    // each note contains result on OS X 10.10.5 on 20160503
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"f*" note:@"true, '*' wildcard works like file globbing, not RE"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"foo*" note:@"true, '*' is zero or more"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"f?o" note:@"true, '?' wildcard works like file globbing, not RE"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"f?" note:@"false, not more then one"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"f?oo" note:@"false, not less than one"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"Foo" note:@"false, is case-sensitive (also see isCaseInsensitiveLike:)"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"[Ff]oo" note:@"true, supports character classes"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"[^F]oo" note:@"false, does not support RE negation in character classes"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"[a-z]oo" note:@"true, supports ranges"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"[[:lower:]]oo" note:@"false, does not support POSIX named classes"];
    [self is:@"]oo" like:@"[]]oo" note:@"false, does not support ']' as first character in a class"];
    [self is:@"]oo" like:@"[\\]]oo" note:@"true, backslash to escape interpretation of ']' as end of class"];
    [self is:@"[oo" like:@"\\[oo" note:@"true, backslash to escape interpretation as start of class"];
    [self is:@"-oo" like:@"[x\\-z]oo" note:@"true, supports escape of '-' in character classes"];
    [self is:@"?oo" like:@"\\?oo" note:@"true, escape with backslash"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"\\?oo" note:@"false, this is not just wildcard matching"];
    [self is:@"*oo" like:@"\\*oo" note:@"true, escape with backslash"];
    [self is:@"foo" like:@"\\*oo" note:@"false, this is not just wildcard matching"];
    [self is:@"\\foo" like:@"\\\\*oo" note:@"true, escape backslash with another backslash"];
}
```

And this code produces these results:

```
[@"foo" isLike:@"f*"] == true // true, '*' wildcard works like file globbing, not RE
[@"foo" isLike:@"foo*"] == true // true, '*' is zero or more
[@"foo" isLike:@"f?o"] == true // true, '?' wildcard works like file globbing, not RE
[@"foo" isLike:@"f?"] == false // false, not more then one
[@"foo" isLike:@"f?oo"] == false // false, not less than one
[@"foo" isLike:@"Foo"] == false // false, is case-sensitive (also see isCaseInsensitiveLike:)
[@"foo" isLike:@"[Ff]oo"] == true // true, supports character classes
[@"foo" isLike:@"[^F]oo"] == false // false, does not support RE negation in character classes
[@"foo" isLike:@"[a-z]oo"] == true // true, supports ranges
[@"foo" isLike:@"[[:lower:]]oo"] == false // false, does not support POSIX named classes
[@"]oo" isLike:@"[]]oo"] == false // false, does not support ']' as first character in a class
[@"]oo" isLike:@"[\\]]oo"] == true // true, backslash to escape interpretation of ']' as end of class
[@"[oo" isLike:@"\\[oo"] == true // true, backslash to escape interpretation as start of class
[@"-oo" isLike:@"[x\\-z]oo"] == true // true, supports escape of '-' in character classes
[@"?oo" isLike:@"\\?oo"] == true // true, escape with backslash
[@"foo" isLike:@"\\?oo"] == false // false, this is not just wildcard matching
[@"*oo" isLike:@"\\*oo"] == true // true, escape with backslash
[@"foo" isLike:@"\\*oo"] == false // false, this is not just wildcard matching
[@"\\foo" isLike:@"\\\\*oo"] == true // true, escape backslash with another backslash
```

So `isLike:` appears to support `?` and `*` like file globbing with backslash `\` to escape special interpretation.  It also supports character classes with `[` and `]` with ranges defined with `-`.  Backslash to escape opening `[`, and backslash to escape `]` and `-` within the class.

Answer (score 8):

The header `NSScriptWhoseTest.h` provides a little more information:

```
@interface NSObject (NSComparisonMethods)
...

- (BOOL)isLike:(NSString *)object;
    // argument should be a string using simple shell wildcards (* and ?).
    // (e.g. "Stev*" or "N?XT").
    // Returns NO if receiver is not an NSString.

- (BOOL)isCaseInsensitiveLike:(NSString *)object;

@end
```

Comment: Together with @JoshCaswell link to [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868), it is likely that '*' and '?' are the only pattern characters. Note that '\' is also allowed for escaping: `[@"F?oo" isLike:@"\\F\\?oo"]` is `true`

Comment: I found out sometime later that this is grossly incomplete. It also allows character classes, ie `isLike:"[abc]foobar"` will return true for "afoobar" as well as "cfoobar"